# How to Display Amount of products being displayed out of the amount in category - Wordpress/Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have a wordpress/woocommerce stored located here - http://www.bootsandlaces.net

On the category page I want it to display...

A. the total amount of products in the loop

B. The total amount of products being displayed using the given filters from the left sidebar.

For example it will display '3 of 350 products'

for an example see here - http://www.footy.com/c/football-boots/?Gender=Kids

Answer (score 0):

[`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class has the information stored in the [property](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Properties) `$found_posts`.